# Java OpenCL: Passing scalar parameter to kernel in JOCL

Tags: java, opencl, jocl

Does there exist a way to pass scalar parameter to kernel in JOCL without creating a new array? In C++ one can simply cast the scalar parameter (for example, int) to void*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are methods like putArg(float), putArg(int), which are passing scalar args to the kernel.

Take a look at their examples.